# Store data from new class instance in an array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to create 4 new users,

```
let JonSnow = new User({ id: 1, name: 'Jon Snow', status: Status.user });
let AryaStark = new User({ id: 2, name: 'Arya Star', status: Status.user });
let SansaStark = new User({ id: 3, name: 'Sansa Stark', status: Status.user });
let JoffreyBaretheon = new User({ id: 4, name: 'Joffrey Baretheon', status: Status.user });
```

In my User class I have a `allUser` function,

```
allUsers() {
    let users: IUser[] = [];

    let user: IUser = {
        id: this.id,
        name: this.name,
        status: this.status
    }

    users.push(user);
    users.forEach((user) => console.log(user));
    return users;
}
```

If I call the the function like so,

```
JonSnow.allUsers();
AryaStark.allUsers();
SansaStark.allUsers();
JoffreyBaretheon.allUsers();
```

It calls the `allUsers` function 4 times, as expected.

How would I store all 4 new users into one array? So I would only need to call the function once to show all users?

Comment: You just shouldn't use 4 different variable names, but instead put them in a users array right when you are creating them.

Comment: Why exactly does each `User` instance have an `allUsers` method which returns an array with only one `IUser`? Is there a case where a `User` might have multiple `IUser` objects?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a module/namespace variable (don't export it so it won't be accessible from outside), like so:

```
let users: IUser[] = [
    new User({ id: 1, name: 'Jon Snow', status: Status.user }),
    new User({ id: 2, name: 'Arya Star', status: Status.user }),
    new User({ id: 3, name: 'Sansa Stark', status: Status.user }),
    new User({ id: 4, name: 'Joffrey Baretheon', status: Status.user })
]
```

and then you have a simple method:

```
allUsers(): IUser[] {
    return users.slice(0);
}
```

Notice that I cloned the `users` array so that who ever gets a reference to it won't be able to change this inner array, but it's not a must.

But there's no real need to have this method in all classes, you can make it static.
But you can also then make this array a static member of the `User` class, so:

```
class User {
    private static users: IUser[] = [];

    constructor() {
        User.users.push(this);
    }

    static allUsers(): IUser[] {
        return User.users.slice(0);
    }
}
```

The you can get all users: `User.allUsers()`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are just trying to convert a bunch of `User` instances into a single array of `IUser` objects.

What I would do is provide a `User` class method that returns an `IUser` object:

```
public toIUser():IUser {
    return {
        id: this.id,
        name: this.name,
        status: this.status
    }
}
```

Then simply map your instances using that function:

```
let allUsers = [JonSnow, AryaStark, SansaStark, JoffreyBaretheon].map(user => user.toIUser());
console.log("all users:", allUsers);
```

[Playground example here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=enum%20Status%20%7B%0A%09user%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20IUser%20%7B%0A%09id%3A%20number%3B%0A%09name%3A%20string%3B%0A%09status%3A%20Status%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20User%20implements%20IUser%20%7B%0A%09id%3A%20number%3B%0A%09name%3A%20string%3B%0A%09status%3A%20Status%3B%0A%09%0A%09constructor(user%3AIUser)%20%7B%0A%09%09this.id%20%3D%20user.id%3B%0A%09%09this.name%20%3D%20user.name%3B%0A%09%09this.status%20%3D%20user.status%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%09%0A%09public%20toIUser()%3AIUser%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20%7B%0A%09%09%09id%3A%20this.id%2C%0A%09%09%09name%3A%20this.name%2C%0A%09%09%09status%3A%20this.status%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20JonSnow%20%3D%20new%20User(%7B%20id%3A%201%2C%20name%3A%20'Jon%20Snow'%2C%20status%3A%20Status.user%20%7D)%3B%0Alet%20AryaStark%20%3D%20new%20User(%7B%20id%3A%202%2C%20name%3A%20'Arya%20Star'%2C%20status%3A%20Status.user%20%7D)%3B%0Alet%20SansaStark%20%3D%20new%20User(%7B%20id%3A%203%2C%20name%3A%20'Sansa%20Stark'%2C%20status%3A%20Status.user%20%7D)%3B%0Alet%20JoffreyBaretheon%20%3D%20new%20User(%7B%20id%3A%204%2C%20name%3A%20'Joffrey%20Baretheon'%2C%20status%3A%20Status.user%20%7D)%3B%0A%0Alet%20allUsers%20%3D%20%5BJonSnow%2C%20AryaStark%2C%20SansaStark%2C%20JoffreyBaretheon%5D.map(user%20%3D%3E%20user.toIUser())%3B%0Aconsole.log(%22all%20users%3A%22%2C%20allUsers)%3B).

PS: I would [avoid using `static` variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026507/why-are-static-variables-considered-evil) as your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Declare static `User` variable as an array:

```
User.users = []
```

In `User` constructor add the current object to the array:

```
User.users.push(this)
```

Then in `allUsers` return the array:

```
allUsers() {
  return User.users
}
```